# Position relative overlaps float:left -

Tags: css, css-float

http://klarbild.probiermau.ch/static/index.html

I have blue boxes floating left.
i have one orange box - position: relative.

The Orange Box should be put **inside** the floating blue boxes, **not overlapping them**.
So the blue boxes should be floating **around** the orange box.

Is this possible? Hints?

Edit:
I want to be able to change the position of the orange box only by using css. The blue boxes should always float around the orange one. Without beeing "hidden" behind the orange box.

Thanks a Lot

Comment: I am using Safari to look at the link you posted, and it shows up correct for me.  the blue boxes are floating **around** the orange.

Comment: If you look at Bild 7 ... Bild 10

So Bild 8 and Bild 9 are hidden behind the orange div...

Comment: Does it matter the position of the orange DIV inside the DOM? It has to be the last div element?

Comment: The design should adapt to different screen sizes - so the orange box will be more left on smaller screens. Would love to do that with css only, without needing to reload the html...

Answer (score 1):

Hint: change the position of orange box and float it to the right (without `position : relative`)

See this example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4Bber/1/

Code:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div>blue 1</div>
    <div>blue 2</div>
    <div>blue 3</div>
    <div>blue 4</div>
    <div>blue 5</div>
    <div>blue 6</div>
    <div id="orange"></div>
    <div>blue 7</div>
    <div>blue 8</div>
    <div>blue 9</div>
    <div>blue 10</div>
    <div>blue 11</div>
    <div>blue 12</div>
    <div>blue 13</div>
    <div>blue 14</div>
</div>
```

Css

```
.wrapper { width: 440px; }
.wrapper div { 
    width      : 100px; 
    height     : 100px;
    background : blue;
    float      : left; 
    margin     : 0 0 10px 10px; 
    color      : #fff;
 }

 #orange { 
    background : orange; 
    width      : 210px; 
    height     : 210px; 
    float      : right;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the Hint - This would indeed work.
But i want the Design to adapt to different screen sizes without adjusting the html.
Very small screen : left: 0
bigger screen left: 200px and so on...

Comment: if this is your purpose, position relative will not make things easier: what does it mean _left : 0/200px_ ? Please edit your question and explain exactly all the contraints that a solution must consider.